# Collision detection problems in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

```js
var u = 8;
var x = [];
var y = [];
var s = {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    l: 1,
};
var e = {
    e: false,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
};

function setup() {
    makefood();
    lime;
}

document.onkeydown = keydown;

function keydown(e) {
    ctrls(e.keyCode, true);
}

function ctrls(keyCode, bool) {
    if (keyCode == 37) {
        s.a = true;
        s.w = false;
        s.d = false;
        s.s = false;
    }
    if (keyCode == 38) {
        s.a = false;
        s.w = true;
        s.d = false;
        s.s = false;
    }
    if (keyCode == 39) {
        s.a = false;
        s.w = false;
        s.d = true;
        s.s = false;
    }
    if(keyCode == 40) {
        s.a = false;
        s.w = false;
        s.d = false;
        s.s = true;
    }
}

function calc() {
    if (s.a === true) {
        s.x -= 1;
    }
    if (s.w === true) {
        s.y -= 1;
    }
    if (s.d === true) {
        s.x += 1;
    }
    if (s.s === true) {
        s.y += 1;
    }
    x.push(s.x);
    y.push(s.y);
}

function makefood() {
    e.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 41);
    e.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 41);
    ctx.fillRect(e.x * u, e.y * u, u, u);
}

function eat() {
    makefood();
    e = false;
    x.push(s.x);
    y.push(s.y);
    s.l++;
    
}

function ctest() {
    if (s.x * u == e.x * u && s.y * u == e.y * u) {
        eat();
    }
}

function draw() {
    for (i = 0; i < s.l; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(x[i] * u, y[i] * u, u, u);
    }
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(x[0] * u, y[0] * u, u, u);
    if (e === true) {
        x.shift();
        y.shift();
    }
    e = true;
}

function timer() {
    clear();
    ctest();
    calc();
    draw();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lime = ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
setup();

setInterval(timer, 100);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="328px" width="328"></canvas>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to call the function makefood() when s.x and s.y are = to e.x and e.y respectively but for some reason it won't work, I have been trying for the longest time, and still nothing.  I am just trying to code the snake game, you can look at the code below. If you need more info just let me know! Thanks to all who help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change all e to e.e

```
function eat() {
    makefood();
    e.e = false;
    x.push(s.x);
    y.push(s.y);
    s.l++;
    
}
function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(x[0] * u, y[0] * u, u, u);
    if (e.e === true) {
        x.shift();
        y.shift();
    }
    e.e = true;
}
```

Comment: I have changed this but it is still not detecting the collision, although this was a good find, thanks so much lol, classic javascript error. it only works twice, so weird

Comment: u mean collision for food or wall